# How can I sync Saved searches to an external hardrive

Tags: macos, mac, software-recommendation

Is there an Mac tool I can use to sync saved searches/smart folders to a external hardrive?

Note: I've tried time machine but I can't include the saved searches. With time machine I can only exclude folders I don't want.

Comment: Is time machine backing up everything the issue? Do you only want to back up your saved searches?

Comment: Yes I only want saved searches backed up